# Can both HTML website and aspx share the same domain?

Tags: asp.net, html, dns

I have an html website and an asp.net website using database sql server 2005. If i want to use the same domain for the both websites, is it possible?

Like www.google.com/htmlwebsite.html and www.google.com/aspnetwebsite.aspx ?? I was trying but the aspx page doesn't open up. Is there a reason why it can't?

I hope i am clear. Thanks so much in advance!!

Comment: It entirely depends on your web server configuration. How is it set up?

Comment: What happens when "the aspx page doesn't open up"? Do you get a 404 error? A server fault?

Comment: @MrLister "HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to an ACL set on the requested resource." is the error !

Comment: @Ram OK, and which of the steps outlined on the different forums that show up in an Internet search for this error message have you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to use the same domain for static (*.html) and dynamic (*.aspx) files.

For the permission error you mentioned, it sounds like you need to either modify the Identity of the AppPool in IIS, or add that Identity to the ACL for the folder/files in the site.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible.

Check whether your webserver is Windows or Apache.
If its Windows , it should support ASPX, ASP.

Try a simple script on your domain to check.

```
<%
Response.Write("Hello World")
%>
```

Comment: Windows is not a web server. You mean IIS

Comment: This is an IIS. Trying to figure out the settings why it isn't opening up :-(